# Sparql query optimization with filters

Tags: optimization, filter, sparql, rdf

What is the most optimized sparql query?

```
select * where 
{ 
   ?a predicate1 ?b. ?a predicate2 ?c 
   FILTER(?b="1" && ?c="2")
}
```

or

```
select * where 
{ 
   ?a predicate1 ?b. ?a predicate2 ?c 
   FILTER(?b= "1") FILTER(?c= "2") 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Optimization depends on execution and execution depends on implementation. Both queries and semantically equivalent and SPARQL engines are free to convert one to the other if that makes execution faster. Though as far as implementations I can imagine go, there are more reasons for the second one to be slower rather than the first one.

Answer (score 0):

So as noted in comments what is the most optimal query will depend on the SPARQL engine being used and the sophistication of its optimiser.  Also the dataset upon which you execute the queries will have a role as well, more on that later.

## Jena Optimisation example

Let's take [Apache Jena](https://jena.apache.org) as an example (disclaimer - I've worked on Jena extensively and am a committer and PMC member on the project).  We can use the [sparql.org query validator](http://sparql.org/$/validate/query) to see how Jena would interpret and optimise the two queries by inputting the queries and selecting the `SPARQL Algebra (general optimisations)` checkbox for the Output selection.

**NB** When sharing SPARQL queries it's helpful if you share valid syntactic queries.  In your examples `predicate1` and `predicate2` are not valid symbols, so for the purposes of this answer I've defined an empty prefix as `PREFIX : <http://example.org/>` and changed those to `:predicate1` and `:predicate2` accordingly.

First variant:

```
(base <http://example/base/>
 (prefix ((: <http://example.org/>))
  (filter (= ?c "2")
   (sequence
    (assign ((?b "1"))
     (bgp (triple ?a :predicate1 "1")))
    (bgp (triple ?a :predicate2 ?c))))))
```

Second variant:

```
(base <http://example/base/>
 (prefix ((: <http://example.org/>))
  (filter (= ?c "2")
   (sequence
    (assign ((?b "1"))
     (bgp (triple ?a :predicate1 "1")))
   (bgp (triple ?a :predicate2 ?c))))))
```

Notice the difference? Well there wasn't any, so for this simplistic case Jena optimises the two queries identically.

The outputs shown here are in Jena's [SPARQL S-Expression](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/notes/sse.html) syntax which is just our way of showing the SPARQL Algebra that the queries translates and optimises into.  It's also worth understanding that query evaluation is bottom-up so the left-most leaf of the expression is evaluated first and its results fed into the parent expression and so on until the whole query has evaluated.  This is important later when I discuss why data matters.

For these queries Jena applies a filter equality optimisation whereby it substitutes the concrete value you're filtering against into the inner algebra and then uses an `assign` operator (the translation of a `BIND` clause in SPARQL syntax) to make the value visible in the outer portions of the query.  This can greatly improve the performance because it allows the query engine to look for exactly matching data immediately and not apply a filter, rather than matching all potential data and applying the filter.

Note that Jena will not do this for all filters of this type because `=` is the value equality operator, so if the value given does not represent a concrete value that we can be assured will exactly match within the data we wouldn't translate it.  To explain this consider changing your query as follows:

```
PREFIX : <http://example.org/>

select * where 
{ 
   ?a :predicate1 ?b. ?a :predicate2 ?c 
   FILTER(?b=1)
   FILTER(?c=2)
}
```

Notice I removed the `"` around the two RHS filter values.  This changes them from representing the exact strings `1` and `2` to representing the numeric values (see [SPARQL 1.1 Query - Syntax for Literals](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#QSynLiterals) for the definition of this).  Once those values are numerics rather than simple literals Jena can no longer apply this optimisation and you instead get the following:

```
(base <http://example/base/>
 (prefix ((: <http://example.org/>))
  (filter (= ?c 2)
   (sequence
    (filter (= ?b 1)
     (bgp (triple ?a :predicate1 ?b)))
   (bgp (triple ?a :predicate2 ?c))))))
```

In this case the filters remain as-is within the query.

Regardless of all the above whether Jena can/will apply this optimisation will also depend on the general complexity of the overall query.  For more complex real world queries there may be many potential optimisations that get used that reorganise the query in a way that means this optimisation isn't possible. On a related note SPARQL scoping rules mean that when these kinds of filters are used over clauses that can result in partially unbound variables (e.g. `OPTIONAL`) the optimisation might not be used. Even in my above examples you can see that Jena only applied the optimisation to one of the filters because the second filter actually applies over the join (the `sequence` operator in this case) between the two BGPs and it doesn't consider the optimisation applicable in that instance.

As a rule Jena prefers correctness to optimisation so if there's a potential to optimise a query in a way that might change the results (i.e. the transformed query is no longer semantically equivalent to the users input query) then we don't apply an optimisation.

## Data Matters

Regardless of how good your optimiser is the data upon which these queries evaluate also matters.  As we saw with then Jena optimisation example above in both cases the queries produced the same optimised algebra which was as follows:

```
(base <http://example/base/>
 (prefix ((: <http://example.org/>))
  (filter (= ?c "2")
   (sequence
    (assign ((?b "1"))
     (bgp (triple ?a :predicate1 "1")))
   (bgp (triple ?a :predicate2 ?c))))))
```

I already mentioned that evaluation is bottom-up from the leftmost leaf which in this case is `(bgp (triple ?a :predicate1 "1"))` i.e. the first thing the query engine is going to do is ask the underlying database for triples that match that basic graph pattern (BGP).

Now let's suppose that `?a :predicate1 "1"` is a rare occurrence in your dataset.  Then this BGP is going to produce relatively few results, each of these results is then processed by the `(assign ((?b "1"))` operator which makes sure that the `?b` variable is added into our results as the original query required.  These results are then passed up to the `(sequence` operator, `sequence` is basically Jena's linear join optimisation i.e. the results from one item in the sequence are used to evaluate the subsequent items in the sequence to limit the results.  So now our small number of results are fed into `(bgp (triple ?a :predicate2 ?c))`, Jena substitutes the `?a` values we already have into this BGP and evaluates it.  Since we had few results from the LHS of the sequence we should have only a few results here so the final `(filter (= ?c "2")` operator has relatively little work to do.  If we assume that `?a :predicate2 "2"` is even rarer within your data then this should be super quick.

But what if instead `?a :predicate1 "1"` was a super common pattern in your data?  You'd have tons of results from the LHS that would feed into the next item of the sequence creating lots of database lookups for `?a :predicate2 ?c` which might match lots more results than are ever going to be retained by the final filter leading to the engine doing lots of unnecessary work.  In this case then the default optimisation would be doing a bad job because it would have been better to evaluate `?a :predicate2 ?c` first and feed those results into `?a :predicate1 ?b`.

Some query engines may actually utilise data statistics during their optimisation process to reorder the triple patterns prior to applying other optimisation.  So in the 2nd scenario I outlined if the engine knows that `?a :predicate1 ?b` is more common in your data than `?a :predicate2 ?c` then it would likely choose to evaluate `?a predicate2 ?c` first. This would then also lead to the engine applying other optimisations differently, so in this example it would probably perform the filter equality optimisation on that second pattern substituting out `?c` instead i.e.

```
(base <http://example/base/>
 (prefix ((: <http://example.org/>))
  (filter (= ?b "1")
   (sequence
    (assign ((?c "2"))
     (bgp (triple ?a :predicate2 "2")))
   (bgp (triple ?a :predicate1 ?b))))))
```

With certain configurations of Jena then statistics are available and used so it might have generated this optimised query instead.

## Conclusions

Query optimisation in any database system is a non-trivial problem and there's no up front way to decide which version of a query is more optimal because it depends on details of your choice of query engine, the choice of underlying database storage and your data itself.

Query optimisers for SPARQL are increasingly smart and sophisticated but they won't work perfectly for every query and data combination you throw at them.

Generally the best way to "optimise" queries is to try variations of real queries with your real data to see how different queries perform.

If you're buying a commercially supported SPARQL solution then it's also worth talking to your support contacts.  They should be able to tell you what their engine does and doesn't support, their recommendations on writing good queries and what tooling they provide for analysing/debugging query performance.